# Rotate plot 90deg for marginal distribution

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I am trying to get marginal distribution plots **in base R** (if not possible, non-base R code is okay, but only for doing the rotating).

**How do you rotate the y-axis marginal plot (in yellow)?**

[image: Complex plot to fix]

The code I have to make this plot:

```
# plot layout
layout_mat <- matrix(c(2, 0,
                       1, 3),
                     nrow = 2,
                     byrow = T)

layout(layout_mat, c(3, 1), c(1, 3))

par(mar = c(3,3,1,1))

# main scatterplot
plot(x = mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec), c("wt", "mpg")],
     xlab = "Vehicle Weight (1000 lbs)",
     ylab = "Miles Per Gallon (MPG)",
     pch = 16,
     cex = seq(3.5, 1.25, length.out = nrow(mtcars)),
     col = rgb(0, 0, 0, .5),
     axes = F,
     xlim = c(1, 6),
     ylim = c(8, 35))
box(lwd = 1.5)
axis(side = 1, at = 1:6, labels = 1:6, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)
axis(side = 2, at = seq(10, 35, 5), label = seq(10, 35, 5), lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1, las = 1)

dx <- density(mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec), "wt"])
dy <- density(mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec), "mpg"])

# x axis plot
par(mar = c(0,3,1,1))
plot(dx, axes = F, main = "", xlab= "", ylab = "", lwd =2)

# y-axis plot
par(mar = c(3,0,1,1))
plot(dy, axes = F, main = "", xlab= "", ylab = "", lwd =2)
rect(xleft = par("usr")[1],
     ybottom = par("usr")[3],
     xright = par("usr")[2],
     ytop = par("usr")[4],
     col = rgb(235, 216, 52, .5*255, maxColorValue = 255))
```

Comment: I think your example is missing `dx =  density(mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec), c("wt")]); 
dy =  density(mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec), c("mpg")])` . Is it enough to do `plot(dy$y, rev(dy$x), type="l", axes = F, main = "", xlab= "", ylab = "", lwd =2)` for the third plot?

Comment: Beautiful! So close... Want to post an answer so I can credit you?

Comment: ... although I think maybe the plot should be `plot(dy$y, dy$x)` to correctly model the density -- so not rotated

Comment: No, I think you had it right the first time. The code with `rev()` matches `plot(dy)`

Comment: from `plot(dy)` there is the tail at higher y values. If using `rev` the tail is on the low y values

Comment: Oh right, nice call!

Comment: @user20650 Do you know how to get the y-axis marginal distribution to fit neatly on the y-axis limits? It extends a bit far below

Comment: You can limit the `density` calculation limits, although Id think about whether this is sensible. The basic plot `dx <- density(mtcars$wt); plot(dx); rug(mtcars$wt)` is produced by drawing the density from a normal kernel with means at the points of the data. As the kernel is symmetric then the tails will extend beyond the data. (You can get kernels that deals with border effects and this can be sensible for some types of data). But just to answer your question on fixing it to the limits you can use `dx <- density(mtcars$wt, from=min(mtcars$wt), to=max(mtcars$wt)); plot(dx); rug(mtcars$wt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to @user20650 for this answer**

Passing the y-axis points for y's density to `x` and the x-axis points for y's density to `y` will plot it flipped:

```
plot(dy$y, dy$x, type="l", axes = F, main = "", xlab= "", ylab = "", lwd = 2)
```